# Como pasar parametros desde un href a una ruta get en laravel 4.2?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Saludos comunidad 

Estoy trabajando con esta ruta  en laravel

```
  Route::get('/{tienda}/{ruta}', array('before' => 'validar_tienda', function($tienda, $ruta)
{...}
```

para invocarla desde la barra del navegador no tengo mayor problema con los parametros dinamicos "tienda y ruta"

La pregunta es como se podria invocarla desde un href?.. algo como lo siguiente

```
href="{{ Route ('/',['mitienda'],'/',['sesionproducto'])  }}"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normalmente deberías poder utilizar el helper route() , siempre y cuando le hayas asignado un nombre a tu ruta:

```
href="{{ route('miruta', ['tienda' => $tienda, 'ruta' => $ruta]) }}"
```

Más información u opciones en la documentación de Laravel: https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/helpers#urls

Comment: Se te agradece @Shaz bendiciones!!